# React - don't accept props in a certain way (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I want to create a button component (as in an example, but I am asking it in a general matter), I want to create three states of the button primary, secondary and tertiary.

```
export interface ButtonProps {
    primary?: boolean;
    secondary?: boolean;
    tertiary?: boolean;
};

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
    primary, 
    secondary, 
    tertiary
 }) => {
 if(primary){
    return(/*PrimaryButton*/);
 }
 else if(secondary){
    return(/*SecondaryButton*/);
 }
 else if(tertiary){
    return(/*TertiaryButton*/);
 }
```

I want my component to **not** accept the parameters if more than one of these parameters are given, for example:

```
<Button primary secondary />
```

Comment: It's simpler to have an enum (or even a string union) with permitted modes instead of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React standpoint, you should instead make [impossible states impossible](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/make-impossible-states-impossible)

However your question is about Typescript rather than React best practives, and you want to have 3 mutually exclusive properties in a type. Use [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for that, e.g.

```
type ButtonProps =
  | {
      primary: boolean
    }
  | {
      secondary: boolean
    }
  | {
      tetriary: boolean
    }
```

if you have shared props between all the variants

```
type ButtonProps = { label: string; onClick: () => void } & (
  | {
      primary: boolean
    }
  | {
      secondary: boolean
    }
  | {
      tetriary: boolean
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to allow a single type, why not make it a single prop?

```js
export interface ButtonProps {
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
};

<Button variant="primary" />
```